# ERR_HRS_SPACE_IN_HDR_NAME failure reason from WAF

Tags: akamai, web-application-firewall

I'm getting a 400 Bad Request response from my WAF/CDN, with the reason for failure being given as `ERR_HRS_SPACE_IN_HDR_NAME`. What is causing this and how can I avoid it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HRS in the error reason is "HTTP Request Smuggling", which is a way of interfering with the sequences of HTTP requests that are received from one or more users by a web server. It's likely you have some unnecessary whitespace in your request headers (probably before the colon - e.g. `Accept : application/json` rather than `Accept: application/json` or preceding the header name - e.g. `[space]Transfer-Encoding: chunked`).

Checking your headers and removing the offending whitespace should prevent this issue.